# Need to apply HTTP Verb constraint using naming convention in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way by which I can restrict an MVC action to a particular `HTTP Verb`. I don't want to apply `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` attribute on every action. Instead I want to use some naming convention for actions & want MVC to use those naming conventions to apply constraint over HTTP Verbs. *[Quite similar to what Web Api uses by deafult]*

For example:

1. SaveUser Action should be HttpPost only [Use Save prefix]
2. PostUser Action should be HttpPost only [Use Post prefix]
3. FindUser Action should be HttpGet only [Use Find prefix]
4. GetUser Action should be HttpGet only [Use Get prefix]

Comment: You could probably write an action filter.

Comment: Why not just decorate the methods with the HTTP verb attributes? It seems like you are attempting to get around an issue that's not really a issue. I prefer to make things obvious

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to stick with a conventional implementation

Comment: In your route mapping you can specify a constraint      `routes.MapRoute(name: "Save", url: "{controller}/{Save...",                defaults: new { controller = .... }, constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "POST" }) }` but not sure how to handle wildcards there. You might need to create your own custom constraint (meaning a class implementing IRouteConstraint) in order to have full control of the action name and http verb. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs